# How set buffer size in android youtube api player

Tags: android, youtube-api

I use youtube player in my android app, And I want know some details. I start play video and video start download into player(buffer). But after some time load end while the band player does not come close to the strip download.
I want know logic how calculate this buffer or maybe I can set up this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what is the exact question but you can make use of the ***`public abstract void onBuffering (boolean isBuffering)`*** method. This method is called when buffering starts or ends. This may occur either before or after onPlaying() when a video starts loading.

For more details check this official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener#onBuffering(boolean)).